# Query about Directory traversal

Tags: apache, http, web, owasp

I'm currently practicing OWASP attacks and I have a question about a particular HTTP GET request:

"GET /loadImage.php?filename=../../../etc/passwd HTTP/1.1"

When I send this request, I receive a response with a status code of 200. However, when I try the following request:

"GET /loadImage.php?filename=../../../home/arun/mywindows.txt HTTP/1.1"

I receive a 404 not found error.

I'm wondering why this is happening, considering that both files should be located in the root directory of the web server. Any insight would be greatly appreciated!